# What does straining a gnat and swallowing the camel mean?

Tags: matthew

Matthew 23:24 of the American Standard Version says, Ye blind guides, that strain out the gnat, and swallow the camel.

What does straining a gnat and swallowing the camel mean?

When is a guide considered blind?

Answer (score 2):

In context the of Matthew 22:1–23:39, this statement is one of “Seven Woes” in Jesus’ diatribe leveled against the Pharisees and Sadducees (two groups of religious leaders of the time).

Before unpacking this further, note the meaning of this phrase is found within the context itself: “Even so ye also outwardly appear righteous unto men, but within ye are full of hypocrisy and iniquity” (Mt 23:28, KJV).  The central theme of these statements of woe address the notion of appearing to be clean (or holy) on the outside (physically) but not really being clean (holy) on the inside (spiritually). The statement itself is one of these woes. The word ‘woe’ (Greek: Οὐαὶ, *ouai*) is an interjection denoting “pain or displeasure” (Bauer 591). So, Jesus is directing some displeasure at the Scribes and Pharisees.

This statement itself contains sharp sonic imagery (as well as visual imagery). Assuming Jesus spoke this in the Aramaic, you have a pun (which registers bitingly sarcastic) since the words ‘camel’ גָּמָל *gamal* and ‘gnat’ גָּלמָ *galma* are similar in the Aramaic (Stein 13). They are both unclean animals (see Leviticus 11:3ff). In addition to the statement registering sonically as a pun, the visual imagery is acute as well. While meticulously observing the law and ceremoniously straining out a tiny unclean critter, the Pharisees ultimately swallow a larger unclean animal—rendering themselves unclean despite their attention to the minutia of the law, but missing the essence of the law—"judgement, mercy, and faith” (Mt 23:23).

Some scholars might dismiss this passage out of hand as “inconsistent” with the teachings of Christ to “love your enemies” (Mt 5:44, KJV) and “does an injustice to the Scribes and Pharisees” (Luz 138). Some might go as far to posit that verses like these fed anti-Semitism culminating in the Holocaust in more recent times (see Luz 138). Albeit, scripture taken out of context can be twisted to one’s own agenda, however, I do not subscribe to this view of inconsistency. In its melieu, I contend this shows us other attributes of Christ (cf “For whom the Lord loveth he chasteneth, and scourgeth every son whom he receiveth” (He 12:6, KJV); and “He that spareth his rod hateth his son: but he that loveth him chasteneth him betimes” (Pr 13:24, KJV)).

You also ask: “When is a guide considered blind?”

This is an astute question. Rhetorically, this is an oxymoron. A guide by definition is some who sees or knows. Here the term ‘guide’ is from the Greek ὁδηγοὶ *hodēgos*, denoting “a leader of the way” or “a teacher of the ignorant and inexperienced” or even a “guide for the blind” (Bauer 553). This last definition (guide for the blind) makes Jesus’ rhetoric register as emphatically oxymoronic. Jesus employs irony as the Pharisees being religious leaders themselves cannot see the truth—cannot see the errors of their ways. They are in fact not guides at all but in a state of spiritual deprivation--blindness. They themselves are the ones who need a guide.

The idea is that while Pharisees are religious leaders (hence spiritual guides), they are in fact blind guides—that is to say, misleading people—with their emphasis on rules and regulations as opposed to emphasizing “judgment, mercy, and faith.”

This is a basic overview—I am sure others probably have deeper insights.

Sources

Bauer, Walter, et. al. *A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament*. University of Chicago 
Press, 1979.

Hagner, Donald H. *Matthew, World Biblical Commentary*. Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1993.

Luz, Ulrich. *Matthew, Hermeneia—A Critical and Historical Commentary on the Bible*. Fortress 
Press, 2007.

Stein, Robert H. *The Method and Message of Jesus’ Teachings*. Westminster Press, 1978.

The Holy Bible, Authorized King James Version, Thomas Nelson, 1972.

Comment: I wonder what source Stein is using for גָּלמָ galma as the Aramaic word for "gnat". I can only find the Aramaic word כלמה/כלמא (kalmah) or כלמתא/קלמתא (kalmta) for "vermin"/"gnat": http://cal.huc.edu/djpa.php?lemma=klmh+N; http://cal.huc.edu/showjastrow.php?page=645; http://cal.huc.edu/showlevy.php?page=1:367.  Perhaps it is based on a reconstruction of Galilean Aramaic. Also, although I suppose the Greek word κώνωψ (konops) could be translating this Aramaic word, the Syriac Peshitta has ܒܳܩ̈ܶܐ (boqe) and it does not appear in the Septuagint for comparison to the Targums.

Comment: A fair question. Stein's does not reference his source, unfortunately. However, this observation is confirmed by at least two others: Black, Matthew. An Aramaic Approach to the Gospels and Acts. Hendrickson Publishers, 1998; and Hagner, Donald H. Matthew, World Biblical Commentary. Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1993.

Answer (score 1):

**What does straining a gnat and swallowing the camel mean?**

Matthew 23:24 of the American Standard Version says, Ye blind guides, that strain out the gnat, and swallow the camel.

The gnat was the smallest unclean creature known to the Israelites (Leviticus 11:21-24), eating it would make them ceremoniously unclean, the camel was among the largest. (Leviticus 11:4)

Jesus uses a hyperbole, they would strain a gnat from their wine because that insect is ceremoniously unclean, while they completely disregarded the more important matters of the Law, an action comparable to swallowing a camel.

Comment: What verb is similar to strain out in this context?